# how to enter data to sql column(data type is text)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a project in asp.net, it is an online bus reservation ticket system.

I have error while I try to insert data into my database.

Data which comes from the text box does not match with the data type of my column.

Column name is `maplink` and datatype is text.

Here is my c# code.

```
 protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JIHAD-PC;Initial Catalog=OBTRS;Integrated Security=True"))
          {
              using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
              {
                  cmd.Connection = con;
                  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ROUTE 
                     ([FROM],[TO],MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,
                       FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SUNDAY,FARE,MAPLINK) 
                      VALUES (" 
                      + DropDownList1.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "," 
                      + DropDownList2.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "," 
                      + monday + "," + thusday + "," 
                      + wednesday + "," + thursay + "," 
                      + friday + "," + saturday + ","
                      + sunday + "," + Int32.Parse(fare.ToString()) + "," 
                      + maplink.Text + ")";//**here is my error<-----------------------**


                  using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter())
                  {
                      adp.SelectCommand = cmd;

                      DataTable tablo = new DataTable();
                      adp.Fill(tablo);


                  }

              }
          }
    }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: 1. You have insert command above but is been used as select ( to fill data). 2. What is data type of your column ? 3. What is error message ?

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean because I am hard noob about asp.net and sql .Can you explain in a simple way.by the way thank you for feedback marc_s

Comment: yes I see now I use as select.I wrote  my data type and column name in question

Comment: error:Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **REALLY** use parametrized queries - **ALWAYS**, no exceptions. Those are safe against SQL injection attacks, and they're often faster, too.

```
protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.ROUTE([FROM], [TO], MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, FARE, MAPLINK) " +
                        "VALUES(@From, @To, @Monday, @Tuesday, @Wednesday, @Thursday, @Friday, @Saturday, @Sunday, @Fare, @Maplink)";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JIHAD-PC;Initial Catalog=OBTRS;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, con))
    {
        // fill the parameters
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@From", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@To", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Monday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = monday;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tuesday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tuesday;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Wednesday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = wednesday;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Thursday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = thursday;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Friday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = friday;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Saturday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = saturday;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sunday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sunday;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fare", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fare;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Maplink", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = maplink.Text;

        // open connection, execute INSERT command, close connection
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I have no idea what your `Monday` through `Sunday` values are - string? Int? Something else entirely? You might need to adapt the above code to match your own datatypes!